# Trigger hudson/cloudbees build from Atlassian Jira?

Tags: build, hudson, jira, build-server, cloudbees

I'm looking for possibility to allow any users of certain project of Jira start (trigger) certain Hudson builds. Is it possible without creating own Jira plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I would have expected this feature to be available with the [Marvelution JIRA Hudson Integration](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.marvelution.jira.plugins.hudson), which offers functionality pretty similar to he one offered by the [JIRA Bamboo Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugin.ext.bamboo) (e.g. build status reporting) - surprisingly though, triggering builds as you desire seems not to be available in either one yet, despite an obvious feature indeed (the *JIRA Bamboo Plugin* has related/partial support at least, see [Running a Bamboo Build when Releasing a Version](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Running+a+Bamboo+Build+when+Releasing+a+Version)).

Consequently you might want to [file a feature request](http://issues.marvelution.com/browse/MARVJIRAHUDSON) for the *Marvelution JIRA Hudson Integration* first rather than developing your own from scratch immediately, maybe it is going to be considered.

Please note that this plugin doesn't support JIRA 5.0 yet, but the respective [version 5.0.0](http://issues.marvelution.com/browse/MARVJIRAHUDSON/fixforversion/10990) is scheduled for May 24, 2012.